# converting text written in 1/8th format to numbers/digits in python

Tags: python

I have text which has numbers in this format

```
"SEP15    1032'0    1040'6    1022'4    1029'0    1031'4    -1'2        9290     1032'6       13361       27522"
```

the  numbers represent fractions in 8th , i.e  1040'6  is actually means 1040 6/8 , which is 1040.75 , and -1'2  is  -1.25 
I am having difficulty in writing a function for  converting this before I put them in a pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lambda` or anonymous function in the  replacement part of `re.sub` function.

```
>>> s = "SEP15    1032'0    1040'6    1022'4    1029'0    1031'4    -1'2        9290     1032'6       13361       27522"
>>> re.sub(r"\b(\d+)'(\d+)\b", lambda m: str(float(m.group(1))+(float(m.group(2))/8)), s)
'SEP15    1032.0    1040.75    1022.5    1029.0    1031.5    -1.25        9290     1032.75       13361       27522'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this -

```
def conv_to_frac(num_str):
    if "'" in num_str:
        n_split = num_str.split("'")
        #Getting only the fractional part out
        frac = str(int(n_split[1])/8.0).split(".")[1]
        num_str = n_split[0] + "." + str(frac)
    return num_str

>>> conv_to_frac("1040'6")
'1040.75'
>>> conv_to_frac("-1'2")
'-1.25'
```

Comment: instead of splitting it again based on the . you could have just added the value to the first split value.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over your numbers by splitting the text then again split the numbers with one quote and just convert the decimal part and add with integer part :

```
>>> s="SEP15    1032'0    1040'6    1022'4    1029'0    1031'4    -1'2        9290     1032'6       13361       27522"
>>> 
>>> [int(i)+float(j)/8 for i,j in [i.split("'") if "'" in i else [i,'0'] for i in s.split()[1:]]]
[1032.0, 1040.75, 1022.5, 1029.0, 1031.5, -0.75, 9290.0, 1032.75, 13361.0, 27522.0]
>>>
```